# Parallel.For List<Int32>

Tags: .net, task-parallel-library

I wrote the following lines of code:

```
    private static List<Int32> GetRandomList_Serial()
    {
        List<Int32> returnValue = new List<int>();
        Random random = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
        {
            returnValue.Add(random.Next());
        }
        returnValue.Sort();
        return returnValue;
    }
```

I then wrote this block of code:

```
    private static List<Int32> GetRandomList_Parallel()
    {
        List<Int32> returnValue = new List<int>();
        Random random = new Random();

        Parallel.For(0, 10000000, y =>
        {
            returnValue.Add(random.Next());
        });

        returnValue.Sort();
        return returnValue;

    }
```

Serial works fine, Parallel throws this exception:

> System.ArgumentException was unhandled by user code
>
> Destination array was not long enough. Check destIndex and length, and the array's lower bounds.

Anyone have an idea why?

Comment: There is no point in parallelizing such a trivial operation.  In addition, you can't really parallelize operations that involve a shared resource like a list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using a List<> which is not thread safe. Use ConcurrentBag<>. I run into this all the time while switching to Parallel loops. It will happen intermittently, not every time so it's hard to detect.

Comment: @SLaks I agree but that wasn't his question. His question was why he was seeing the error and it will provide valuable info for others who have similar problems when dealing with parallel loops on tasks that require it.

Comment: `Random` is also not thread safe, so don't be surprised if this continues to fail after switching to `ConcurrentBag<>`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `List<>` isn't thread safe.  But, you CAN parallelize this by pre-allocating the List to your wanted size, and then use [] (index) to fill the values.

In other words, don't grow your array in parallel.  Grow it at start, then fill it in parallel.

EDIT:

Some more info.

`List<>` is a simple array that can grow for the convenience.  So if you pre-allocate it (grow it to LENGTH of 1000 right at a start) the size (`.Count`) of it won't change during the filling.

So, if Parallel.For uses any kind of partitioning, it will assign different indices to each thread that will process the loop.  And, each ELEMENT of the array will be filled exactly ONCE.

I don't see any problem with that, other than `Random.Next()` isn't thread safe and might return gibberish.  But, it is supposed to do that, right?

NEW EDIT:

Even more info:

If using a List<> is a requirement, pre-allocating would mean:

```
List<int> myList=new List<int>(MY_COUNT);
//  very unefficient method of pre-allocation, 
//  but there is no other way to assign .Count
for (int n=0; n<MY_COUNT; n++) {
    myList.Add(0);
}
//  proceed with Parallel.For
```

If you can SWITCH types to something else, I would recommend an array for this:

```
int[] myList=new int[MY_COUNT];
//  proceed with Parallel.For
```

Comment: Even if the list is initialized to the correct size, you could still have a problem -- just not the specific problem reported in the question.  For example, two threads could write different values to the same position in the list, which would cause the first such value to be lost.

Comment: Zou are saying that parallel.for uses SAME index in two different threads?  Ummmm....

Comment: Daniel, it is possible that two threads would use the same index.  A second thread could read the list's length before the first thread had a chance to increment it.  Then, both threads would write to the same index in the list's underlying array.

Comment: @phoog No, it won't, because my advice (see my answer) is to PRE-ALLOCATE the list.  So the list size (length) is always the same during Parallel.For.

Comment: Daniel, the list's *capacity* is not the same as its *element count*.

Comment: ...(sorry, can't edit comments on my phone for some reason)... and the index of the next item to add is determined by the element count. When you add the first item to a list that was pre-allocated to capacity X, the destination index is zero.  That is always equal to the element count of the list at the beginning of the call to Add.  If two threads call Add at the same time, they could write the element to the same index in the pre-allocated array.

Comment: ...perhaps you should explain more thoroughly what you mean by pre-allocate. I assumed that you were talking about the constructor that takes an int argument to allocate storage for the given number of elements. Did you mean something else?

Comment: @phoog here - I added an explanation on pre-allocating, and an alternative to List<> that would be as fast as possible in this scenario, since I suppose that OP doesn't need ad-hoc appending, insertion, or something else with the list.